# Only one index label in the dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with the ecoli dataset from http://archive.ics.uci.
edu/ml/datasets/Ecoli. The values are separated by tabs. I would like to index each column and give them a name. But when i do that using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
ecoli_cols= ['N_ecoli', 'info1', 'info2', 'info3', 'info4','info5','info6,'info7','type']
d= pd.read_table('ecoli.csv',sep= ' ',header = None, names= ecoli_cols)
```

Instead of creating the name for each index it creates a 6 new columns. But i would like to have those index name for each of the columns that i already have. And later i would like to extract information from this dataset. So it is important to have them as comma separated or in tables. Thanks

Comment: Use `sep= '\t'` instead `sep=' '`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `url` with data and separator `\s+` - one or more whitespaces:

```
url = 'http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/ecoli/ecoli.data'

ecoli_cols= ['N_ecoli', 'info1', 'info2', 'info3', 'info4','info5','info6','info7','type']
df = pd.read_table(url,sep= '\s+',header = None, names= ecoli_cols)
#alternative use parameter delim_whitespace
#df = pd.read_table(url, delim_whitespace= True, header = None, names = ecoli_cols)


print (df.head())

      N_ecoli  info1  info2  info3  info4  info5  info6  info7 type
0   AAT_ECOLI   0.49   0.29   0.48    0.5   0.56   0.24   0.35   cp
1  ACEA_ECOLI   0.07   0.40   0.48    0.5   0.54   0.35   0.44   cp
2  ACEK_ECOLI   0.56   0.40   0.48    0.5   0.49   0.37   0.46   cp
3  ACKA_ECOLI   0.59   0.49   0.48    0.5   0.52   0.45   0.36   cp
4   ADI_ECOLI   0.23   0.32   0.48    0.5   0.55   0.25   0.35   cp
```

But if want use your file with separator as tab:

```
d = pd.read_table('ecoli.csv', sep='\t',header = None, names= ecoli_cols)
```

And if separator is `;`:

```
d = pd.read_table('ecoli.csv', sep=';',header = None, names= ecoli_cols)
```

Comment: It did not work for me. For some reason my pc is cannot connect the url method. And when i gave '\t' in my code it produces the same result as before.

Comment: And what about `sep= '\s+'` instead `\t` ?

Comment: same as `\t`. It does not change.

Comment: Hmmm, then it seems some data related problem. Can you send me your file `ecoli.csv` to my email in my profile?

Comment: Separator is `;`, so need `sep=';'`